# Need correct total, Power BI table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure in which i am dividing total number of contractual months from total number of  months. I am getting correct result, but the total in the bottom is not correct.

[image]

The first column is a unique ID, Third and fourth columns are numerator and denominator, Second column is the result of the division, I want to count those IDs, where the division is between 0.75 and 1.00

Here are my calculations

Var Check=DIVIDE([Month of Engagement],[Months In Contract L30])
RETURN
IF(HASONEVALUE('Fact - TABLE'[ID]),IF(Check>=0.75 && Check<=1.00,DISTINCTCOUNT(ID),0),SUMX('Fact - TABLE',IF(Check>=0.75 && Check<=1.00,DISTINCTCOUNT(ID),0)))

Please let me know, how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

For Total, you should change 3th parameter of IF to:

```
CALCULATE (
    SUMX (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            tab,
            FILTER (
                ALL ( tab ),
                VAR __Check =
                    DIVIDE ( 'Tab'[Month of Engagement], Tab[Months In Contract L30] )
                RETURN
                    __Check < 1
                    && __Check > 0.75
            )
        ),
        1
    )
)
```

Below my test example (for testing only I have put check variable in first IF
IF ( Check >= 0.75 && Check <= 1.00, Check, 0 ) to see if check calculation is correct):

[image]

```
Measure = 
VAR Check =
    DIVIDE (
        SUM ( 'Tab'[Month of Engagement] ),
        SUM ( Tab[Months In Contract L30] )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( 'Tab'[ID] ),
        IF ( Check >= 0.75 && Check <= 1.00, Check, 0 ),
        CALCULATE (
            SUMX (
                CALCULATETABLE (
                    tab,
                    FILTER (
                        ALL ( tab ),
                        VAR __Check =
                            DIVIDE ( 'Tab'[Month of Engagement], Tab[Months In Contract L30] )
                        RETURN
                            __Check < 1
                            && __Check > 0.75
                    )
                ),
                1
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Your solution is correct!! but this is working on the dummy data entered by us on a blank PBI file, but when i am trying to replicate the same measure in a live AAS environment then i am getting blank...

Answer (score 0):

Measure =
VAR Check =
DIVIDE (
[Month of Engagement] ,
[Months In Contract L30]
)
RETURN
IF (
HASONEVALUE ( 'Tab'[ID] ),
IF ( Check >= 0.75 && Check <= 1.00, Check, 0 ),
CALCULATE (
SUMX (
CALCULATETABLE (
'Tab',
FILTER (
ALL ( 'Tab' ),
VAR __Check =
DIVIDE ( [Month of Engagement], [Months In Contract L30] )
RETURN
__Check >=0.75
&& __Check <=1.00
)
),
1
)
)
)

Here are the brief definitions

Month of Engagement:= CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(
SUMMARIZE('table','table'[MONTH_OF_ENGAGEMENT],"Count",DISTINCT('table'[MONTH_OF_ENGAGEMENT]))),'table'[FREQUENCY_FLAG]="Y")+0

Here MONTH_OF_ENGAGEMENT is value extracted from a date as YYYYMM

Months In Contract L30:=
Var DBRefreshDate30= [Database Refresh Date]-30
RETURN
DATEDIFF(DBRefreshDate30,[Database Refresh Date],MONTH)+1

Now basis on dividing Month of Engagement from Months In Contract L30, i am deriving a percentage, and checking if that percentage lies between 0.75 and 1.00

Comment: Prawdopodobnie miary jakie używasz w DIVIDE, są bardziej złożone niż zwykłe SUM; Możesz podać ich definicje edytując swoją odpowiedź?

Comment: I got the fix, i have modified the else part of hasonevalue with the expression below ,,, SUMX(
    FILTER(
        VALUES('Table'[id]),divide(Month of engagement, Months in Contract L30)>=0.75 && divide(Month of engagement, Months in Contract L30)<=1.00),1))